# Clion exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

Tags: c++, clion

I get a weird exit code in clion:

> exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)

This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);

    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    int arr[30007][5];

    for (i = 1; i <= 30000; i++)
        arr[0][i] = 1;

    //...

    return 0;
}
```

I tested it and find out its because of this line:

```
int arr[30007][5];
```

I had no problem in **declaration of array in size of less than 1.000.000** 2 days ago and now I get this error.
I changed nothing in Clion.

What should I do?

Comment: As listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx) (assuming the platform you are using is Windows), it is the exception code equal to "STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW". Stack sizes are, typically, small, and such an array occupies ~0.57MB already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error number `0xC00000FD` stands for "stack overflow" (I suppose your platform is Windows). Under Windows local variables are allocated on the stack (as on most other platforms too) and `int arr[30007][5]` is pretty big (30007 * 5 * 4 = 600140 bytes) and stacks are usually rather small (typically around 1 Mb, again platform dependant)

You have many options:

1. use `std::vector` instead of raw arrays (preferred)
2. declare the array as static (`static int arr[30007][5];`), then it won't reside on the stack anymore
3. increase the stack size of your executable. This is highly platform/too dependant.
4. allocate the array dynamically

Comment: i changed to static and it worked.
but i mostly used this:
long long int arr[500000]
and had no problem. what happened now ?!
could it be for windows updates ?

Comment: Probably the stack size was bigger on that builds. The stack size is not a matter of the C language but a matter of the build tools (C compiler and linker). I have no idea how to change the stack size on your platform.

Comment: Point 2 was a life saver, although I do prefer point 1 but legacy code doesnt change that often. For point 2: Was there any documentation that I could refer to that highlights this? Also how does one know what the stack limit is on operating systems? Thank you.